# Use a timedate defined in a php variable as the starting point for a datetimepicker range

Tags: php, jquery, html, datetimepicker

Instead of the servers system clock being used as the starting point for the range minDate 0 and maxdate 7 I'd like to use the time I have stored in the php variable $whentime in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.

```
<script> 
$(function() {
$( "#datetimepicker" ).datetimepicker({
hourGrid: 4,
minuteGrid: 10,
dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
numberOfMonths: 2,
minDate: 0,
maxDate: 7
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to explicitly set the time based on that PHP variable, you could do this:

```
<?php $whentime = date('Y-m-d H:i'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    value:'<?php echo $whentime; ?>', 
    format:'Y-m-d H:i',
});
</script>
```